# What numbering systems have been developed using Unicode characters that are NOT letters of the English alphabet or Arabic numerals?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, real-numbers, cryptography

I see many base-16, base-64 etc numeric systems use the 0-9, a-z, A-Z -_, etc, but what systems are people using that make use of **other** unicode characters, without using any English letters or Arabic numerals.

I am thinking of developing a base-12 system using shapes in Unicode, so if there's anything like that I could learn from, it would help a lot!

If you are curious to see all the characters, try this out in terminal

```
php -r 'for ($x = 161; $x < 155000; $x++) {echo html_entity_decode("&#".$x.";",ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8");}'
```

EDIT

To be perfectly clear, I mean no numbers and no english letters.

Comment: why not simply $0$-$9$,$A$-$B$ for base $12$?

Comment: Have you look at wiki entry of [Duodecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecimal)?

Around 2015, two code points `U+218A` and `U+218B` has been added to
unicode to denote the $10^{th}$ and $11^{st}$ alphabet of a base-12 number system. This is poorly supported in most browsers. The two alphabets are supposed to look like `2` and `3` turned upside down. $$\require{HTML}
\newcommand{\ten}{\style{display:inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg);}{2}}
\newcommand{\eleven}{\style{display:inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg);}{3}}
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, \,\ten\!, \,\eleven\!.
$$

Comment: @achillehui I am NOT interested in the conventional base-12 system at all, as there is no reason outside of convention to use them. I am asking if systems have been developed that do not use these 0-9 a-z A-Z character sets, but other characters in unicode.

Comment: @j-w-tanner I am NOT interested in the conventional base-12 system at all, as there is no reason outside of convention to use them. I am asking if systems have been developed that do not use these 0-9 a-z A-Z character sets, but other characters in unicode.

Comment: I did read the question.  I think my answer is on point.  The particular characters you use do not matter to how things work in a particular base.  You just change the addition and multiplication tables to use the new characters.  It is like I chose $52$ Chinese characters and decided to transliterate English using them as my upper/lower case alphabet.  I would still be writing English, but with a nonstandard character set.  Most people would ignore what I wrote because it was too hard to interpret.

Comment: Seems a bit like an AB problem to me. I'm not an expert, but every base-12 system I've encountered has used the digits 0-9 and letters or contrived glyphs for the other two. I doubt there is a "standard" system using utterly different characters, so you should probably just make one yourself. Also, I think framing this question in terms of Unicode confuses the issue: What you're really asking is if there is a set of (nonalphanumeric) characters commonly used to denote the digits of base 12; whether those characters are found in the Unicode spec is a separate issue (and off-topic for Math SE).

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for that Ross, I am sure it will help someone reading this. I am looking for non-traditional numeric character sets that may be published in obscurity, or developed in universities, for video games etc. I understand the concept that I can use any character. I am simply seeking the characters. Thanks for linking the Klingon. Here's examples of what I am looking for, though I am hoping someone in a math department may have other, more sensical, geometric they made for fun: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems

I did a poor job explaining my question.

Comment: ", but what systems are people using that make use of other unicode characters"  Why would anyone *bother* to create such a system.  I can't think of any interest this would hold.  But if you want to just pick any dang 12 images you want and assign them any value you want.  Let ladybugs=1, crickets=2, etc. I honestly have no idea why you are asking this question or what answer you expect to find.  I mean what/ ... Are you asking about the *history* of fiction and puzzle making? Are you asking about what writers of television shows and comic strip have used? I don't see this as a *math* quest.

Answer (score 1):

The base and the characters are completely independent.  The base says how many characters you need, so for hexadecimal you need $16$ distinct digits (though digits has a root of $10$ I will use that for any base).  Traditionally the digits are $0-9, A-F$ but you could use any $16$ distinct characters to express numbers in hexadecimal.  If you want a base $12$ system, you need $12$ distinct characters to express the digits.  Whether you get them from Unicode, using $0-9, A,B$ or glyphs from Klingon does not change how we interpret the numerals.

Comment: Thanks for restating my question. I am asking for examples of systems that use none of these characters, at all. 

Please link me to the Klingon systems, I am aware of how number bases operate, I am developing an application using base-12 and base-60. Just looking for sources to find the characters I might want to choose.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language) is the Wikipedia article which gives the characters in Klingon.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the question. Sorry if my response was salty. You helped me say what I really meant, so I asked it in a separate question here. YOU ROCK ROSS


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693406/is-there-is-a-set-of-geometric-symbols-commonly-used-to-denote-the-digits-of-bas